# SharePoint Online - List view webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, json-formatting

I have a category list and there is a view which shows category column only. I have about 30 categories listed here. How can I display all the categories say 6 across and in 5 rows. Does it make sense?

I need this for dynamic filtering.

Comment: You can use [JSON view formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting). Check [this sample](https://github.com/ganesh-sanap/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/honeycomb-link) for example.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ganesh Sanap.

Of course, you can also choose to use **Gallery view** to achieve your needs.

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Go to the list as a site admin

2.Click "**All Items**" on the top right

[image]

3.Select **Gallery**

[image]

4.Then, click "**All Items**" again. And click "**Format current view**".

[image]

5.On the Format View panel, click "**Edit card**".

[image]

6.Then, click "**Advanced mode**"

[image]

7.You can modified the width value to meet 6 * 5 rows

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, when I drop the gallery view as a webpart then it doesn't work as intended. For example, If i click on the card it goes to the list item so I have to click on the round thing which appears on mouse over. Is there a way to display a list in a dropdown ?

Comment: From my research and testing, there is currently no way to display a list in a dropdown.